# How to make thumbnail and preview work for shortcut file on Win 7/8

Tags: windows, shortcut, preview

I am learning to write a Windows shell thumbnail handler (IThumbnailProvider implementation), according to the sample project from Microsoft (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppShellExtThumbnailHandler-32399b35).

Everything works just fine until I noticed there is one problem with this thumbnail handler: for a shortcut file that links to the file type registered by the sample DLL, it simply cannot show the thumbnail and preview on Windows 7/8/8.1, it only works on Windows 10. A screenshot might better demonstrate the issue.

On Windows 7:
[image: shortcut files not showing thumbnail or preview on Windows 7]

From the screenshot, you can clearly see that the shortcut links to a .recipe file cannot show the thumbnail and the preview.
I also tried Sumatra and Adobe Acrobat Reader, neither of them work.

However, PowerPoint 2016 (.pptx) somehow works without a problem.

Here's a screenshot that was taken on Windows 10:
[image: thumbnail and preview works on Windows 10]

Any idea how to make the thumbnail/preview work on Windows 7/8?